# cartalyst extensions' routes only set after first test

Tags: laravel, phpunit

Please help I'm using Laravel 5.5 with Cartalyst Platform 7.0 and Phpunit 6.0. I have been trying a lot to install extensions in a testing environment but when the first test runs the extensions routes are not defined so the test returns 404. The second test and the rest of the tests pass because the routes now exist. If I echo(count(\Route::getRoutes())) the first test it is 11 and the rest it is 329.

TestCase

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase as BaseTestCase;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;
use Sentinel;

abstract class TestCase extends BaseTestCase
{
    use TestData, CreatesApplication;

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->app['Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel']->disableMiddleware();

        Sentinel::getUserRepository()->setModel(\App\Models\User::class);
        Sentinel::getPersistenceRepository()->setUsersModel(\App\Models\User::class);

        $this->setUpDatabase();
    }

    protected function setUpDatabase()
    {
        Artisan::call('migrate');
        Artisan::call('extension:install');
        Artisan::call('extension:enable');
    }
}
```